# Applescript | Attribute "AXFrontmost", why can't the value be set to false?

Tags: applescript, automator

I can't change the "AXFrontmost" attribute value to false

As you can see, this code generates a loop

```
tell application "System Events"
    
    set front_process to name of first process whose frontmost is true
    
    tell process front_process
        try
            repeat while (value of attribute "AXFrontmost") is true
                set value of attribute "AXFrontmost" to false
            end repeat
            
        on error
            get properties of attribute "AXFrontmost"
            
        end try
    end tell
    
end tell
```

And in relation to the attribute property "AXFrontmost", the value of settable is true

The methods I found to **FORCE** the frontmost to false are toggling the visible status:

```
repeat while (value of attribute "AXFrontmost") is true
    set visible to false
    delay 0.01
    set visible to true
end repeat
```

And the other way is using CMD + TAB key codes:

```
repeat while (value of attribute "AXFrontmost") is true
    key code 48 using command down
end repeat
```

So, Why does this behavior occur ? given that the **settable property is true.**

Are there any other ways to force the value of attribute "AXFrontmost" to false? Besides the ones I already mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

Well, only one process can be frontmost.

For this, i would just « tell application Finder to activate »
This should set frontmost flag to false for every process.
To set Finder’s flag to false, « tell me to activate » should work.